# SFML Sprite isn't showing on the window even though it isn't giving me any errors

Tags: sfml

I'm working with a ref class and using SFML for the graphics, so at the beginning the problem I encounter was facing non-managed members in a managed class, I fixed that problem but now, I'm unable to see the sprite in the window i'm working

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#pragma make_public(sf::Sprite)
using namespace sf;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
namespace GameModel {
 public ref class Grass {
 public:
    Sprite* Sprite;
    Texture* Texture;
    int Size;
    Grass(int size) {
        Size = size;
        Texture = new sf::Texture();
        Sprite = new sf::Sprite(*Texture);
        Texture->loadFromFile("Imagenes/Grass.png");
        //Image is 500x500px
        Sprite->setTexture(*Texture,true);
        Sprite->setScale(float(Size / 500), float(Size / 500));
    }
    void Draw(sf::RenderTarget& rt) {
        rt.draw(*Sprite);
    }
    void Move(float x, float y) {
        Sprite->setPosition(x, y);
    }

};
public ref class Garden {
public:
    List <Grass^>^ Grass;
    Garden() {
        Grass = gcnew List<GameModel::Grass^>();
    }
};
}
using namespace GameModel;
int main(){
  sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 800), "SFML works!");
  Grass^ T = gcnew Grass(25);
  T->Move(25, 0);
  while (window.isOpen())
    {
     sf::Event event;
     while (window.pollEvent(event))
     {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
     }

     window.clear();
     T->Draw(window);
     window.display();
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your render window should be drawing your sprites, not the opposite.

This should work :
`window.draw(T);`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, turns out the function setScale wasn't really working, so I changed the member:

```
int Size;// I changed this
float Size;// for this
```

after that the function work just fine and the project work as it should